# Looping through list to create new workbooks based upon criteria

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to create a loop that will take a region rollup tab, as well as individual store tabs within that region, into a new workbook and save with that region name. I feel like I could do one of the following:

```
x    R1         R1
     Store1     R1
     Store2     R1
x    R2         R2
     Store3     R2
x    R3         R3
     Store4     R3
     Store5     R3
x
```

I think I could do, "take all tabs between each X and copy to new workbook" or "for every unique region name, offset to the left to find the tab to copy over into a new workbook".

Problem is, I don't know how to do any of this! Could anyone please help in giving any guidance on how this type of loop could be created?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is to at least make an attempt and get some code together. The SO community will help you fix broken code, but they generally don't write code for you from scratch.

Comment: ok, thanks! I'll take a stab at it and come back. Apologies in advanced for any messiness :)